# Is it possible to change vscode settings from my custom extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension and I want to add a few values on the entry `"file.associations"` in the settings file when the user install my extension.

Is it possible? I can't find any resource in the documentation.

If someone can guide me in where to look for, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can change vscode settings from [extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api)

[Create your first Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)
[Tutorial 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-your-first-visual-studio-code-extension)

What can extensions do?

- Change the look of VS Code with a color or icon theme - [Theming](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/theming)
- Add custom components & views in the UI - [Extending the Workbench](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/extending-workbench)
- Create a Webview to display a custom webpage built with HTML/CSS/JS - [Webview Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview)
- Support a new programming language - Language Extensions Overview
  Support debugging a specific runtime - Debugger Extension Guide